# Track a folder which is initialized from a repository

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I want to create a public repository `A`. In `A`, the code will be initialized from several public repositories. For example, I want to have https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient as a code base in folder `A/monaco-languageclient`.

Then, I will modify the code inside `A/monaco-languageclient`. I don't want the change to impact the public repository of TypeFox, whereas I want to track all the change for me in GitHub.

One possible setting for this is:

1. fork https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient to my GitHub
2. add my monaco-languageclient as a submodule of A

This setting does allow me to track my changes in monaco-languageclient. However, I realize in the GitHub webpage of repository `A`, the submodule always points to the initial commit of monaco-languageclient.

[image]

So my questions are:

1. how to let A point to my last version of monaco-languagelclient in GitHub webpage?
2. is the whole setting (i.e., git, fork, submodule) correct for what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Even if GitHub does not always reflect the last version, you can for the Git repository itself to update to [track the lastest from a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309), in  your `.gitmodules` file

That way, any `git clone --recurse-submodules`, or `git submodule update --init --recursive --remote` would fetch and update that submodule.

If you then add, commit and push back, that will also update the reference of `monaco-languageclient`

Comment: I'm using `git version 2.20.1`. So I could do `git config -f .gitmodules submodule.monaco-languageclient.branch master` to configure `.gitmodules`, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.